# Detect shutdown as SYSTEM user

Tags: windows, delphi, service, shutdown

I have an application that is started by a service. The application has no User Interface, it contains a DataModule and a TMyApplication implementation that calls Forms.Application.HandleMessage in a loop (like SvcMgr.TServiceApplication). I hooked the MainWindow to log any messages the hidden window of Forms.Application receives.

- If I manually start the application so it runs on my useraccount, I receive WM_QUERYENDSESSION and WM_ENDSESSION messages on the hidden window of Forms.Application when logging off/shutting down.
- If I start my application using the service, the application runs under the SYSTEM account. When running under the system account I receive only one message, `$0000001A` (WM_WININICHANGE?), at systemshutdown before my application is forcefully terminated by Windows. So no WM_QUERYENDSESSION and WM_ENDSESSION messages.

How can I detect a Windows shutdown on a SYSTEM account and close my application gracefully?

Comment: Why wouldn't you just run everything out of your service?

Comment: I know it doesn't answer your question, but running an process under the SYSTEM account is considered to be very bad practice. If you are already aware of this then I apologise for wittering on.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have your service notify your sub-application.

Here's some information about how the service control manager notifies your service:

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/netfxbcl/thread/063cef3a-de94-44d5-8f2e-4e63c3cfdee8

Do a FindWindow, and PostMessage(hwnd, WM_ENDSESSION) yourself.

Comment: Yes, that is the workaround I am considering. I can override the `DoShutDown` method of TService and close my applications. I was just wondering if there is a way to detect shutdown from the application itself.

Comment: You are running an end-user application in a service context, so you are already coloring outside the lines, as far as MS is concerned.  You will have to hack this yourself.